# Is 'hypothecate' anything to do (in origin or meaning) with 'hypothetical'?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I had never come across the word before but apparently a [hypothecated tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothecated_tax) is one in which ring-fenced funds are collected by taxation to pay for a specific government expenditure. This kind of tax is being suggested in the UK in order to fund the National Health Service in the future.

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90584?redirectedFrom=hypothecate#eid) appears to be defining the verb 'hypothecate' in a way that is definitely different in meaning to 'hypothetical' :

> 1. trans. To give or pledge as security; to pledge, pawn, mortgage.

'Hypothetical' is from 'hypothesis' which the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90588#eid1061322) tells me comes from Greek : ὑπό under + θέσις placing. So a hypothesis is an argument 'placed under' a statement.

The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90584?redirectedFrom=hypothecate#eid) gives the etymology of 'hypothecate' as :

> hypothēcāt-, participial stem of medieval Latin hypothēcāre , < hypothēca hypothec n.: see -ate suffix3. Compare French hypothéquer.

But this all seems a bit muddled to me both in the origin (would not 'hypothecate' have a Greek etymology, intially ?) and in the present English meaning (is not the ring-fenced tax an opposite of a hypothetical tax ?).

It is especially odd when the [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90584?redirectedFrom=hypothecate#eid) then offers a second meaning for 'hypothecate' as :

> 2. trans. = hypothesize v. 2.

thus implying either the same origin or the same meaning for the word as 'hypothetical'.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not an answer, but the Dutch for _mortgage_ is _hypotheek_. I'm not surprised at the meaning of _hypothecated_ and I would assume a different origin for both words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to the origin and meaning lies in the Greek root given by [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hypothecate), where they distinguish between θεκε, *theke* and θεσις, *thesis,* as the Greek roots of 'hypothecate' and 'hypothesis'.

θεκε, *theke*, is a containment of some kind or a building (*apotheke* is a barn, [Strong 596](http://biblehub.com/greek/596.htm)). So 'υποθεκε, *hupotheke*, is that which, metaphorically, is under a building - namely the pledge or mortgage.

Therefore, to hypothecate is, historically, to lay something down, financially, to support the purchase of a building.

Whereas to hypothesize is to lay down an argument in order to support a theory about experimental evidence or observed phenomena.

---

To hypothecate is to lay down money as a pledge.

To hypothesize is to lay down a theory beneath data or phenomena.

---

NOTE : It was @user159691 who drew attention to the Greek roots by providing the reference to Etymonline in an answer which, for some reason, is now deleted.

---

Comment: Both words are derived from the verb *τίθημι* 'to put, to place', including all the millions of metaphors for  abstract 'putting' or 'placing'.

Answer (score 1):

Indians are very familiar with the word, though we never bothered to find its origin.Transport vehicles  bought on bank loan in India are required to have a shout box with the phrase "hypothecated to so and so bank". It just means the chap has pawned his wife's gold ornaments or his family property to buy a work truck.
Growing up, I couldn't help reading every one of those, while waiting in a traffic jam. Its a 'hard to miss' word, if you drive in India. Many wouldn't know the name of the current President but would've heard this word.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciated.