# Does the etymology of "tithe" include the Greek "tithenai"?

Tags: etymology

A [recent question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/429589/142322) on EL&U elicited the following etymonline entry:

> ***[Hypothecate](https://www.etymonline.com/word/hypothecate):***
>   1680s, "pledge (something) without giving up control of it; pawn; mortgage,"....from ***Greek hypotheke "a deposit, pledge, mortgage,***" from hypo- "beneath, under"  ***+ tithenai "to put, to place”***.

I'd like to know whether the Greek word *tithenai* features in the etymology of the English word *tithe*.

> **tithe** *noun*
>   One tenth of annual produce or earnings, formerly taken as a tax for the support of the Church and clergy.
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tithe)

The dictionary entry traces the etymology back to Old English:

> Old English tēotha (adjective in the ordinal sense ‘tenth’, used in a specialized sense as a noun), tēothian (verb).

And so does etymonline:

> a tenth part (originally of produce) due as support of the clergy, c. 1200, from Old English teogoþa (Anglian), teoþa (West Saxon) "tenth," from Proto-Germanic *teguntha, from PIE *dekmto-, from PIE root *dekm- "ten." Retained in ecclesiastical sense while the form was replaced in ordinal use by tenth.

So there might not be a direct link between *tithenai* and *tithe*.

Further, *tithe* is more directly related to *tenth* than it is to *giving*. "Tithe" was coined around 1200 according to etymonline, with *hypothecate* appearing about half a millenia hence, so I'm discounting *hypothecate* from the etymology of *tithe* on timing alone.

However, with *tithenai*'s "to put, to place" appearing to be not far off *tithe*'s connotation of "to give" in the money-related usage of the term, there appears to be at least a superficial, tangential link between *tithe* and *tithenai*. Even so, the link is such a stretch that I was hesitant about posting the question, until I stumbled upon the following:

> For centuries, visitors and dignitaries attending the Olympics would contribute spectacular gifts---*treasures*---from their cities or homelands, which were housed in a newly constructed *thesauros*, from the root of *tithenai*, which later gave us both *treasure* and *tithe*.
>   [- Wordcatcher: An Odyssey into the World of Weird and Wonderful Words, by Phil Cousineau](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=m8lJVgizhbQC&pg=PT275&lpg=PT275&dq=link%20between%20tithenai%20and%20tithe&source=bl&ots=3GiXy2wyqc&sig=bvjI9sXIL_YH_-rhtqKSSrqHKjU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBybbq3JDZAhXEXLwKHZedAEEQ6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=link%20between%20tithenai%20and%20tithe&f=false)

Can anyone confirm the link between *tithe* and *tithenai* or, alternatively, completely dissociate the words from each other?

Comment: The verb is actually _tithemi_ to put [Strong 5087] http://biblehub.com/strongs/greek/5087.htm. _Tithenai_ is, I think, the participle but my grammar is not beside me at the moment.

Comment: @NigelJ: It seems to be the present active infinitive.

Comment: _Tithe_ wasn’t coined around 1200—it’s attested with the meaning given around 1200. The word itself is much older, as the Etymonline entry shows. It’s actually the more or less regular outcome of the PIE ordinal ‘tenth’. The modern ‘tenth’ is a more recent and transparent formation.

Comment: The roots apprear to be different going back to PIE : *tithe* https://www.etymonline.com/word/tithe has the PIE root ***dekm-*** (ten) https://www.etymonline.com/word/*dekm-?ref=etymonline_crossreference - while *tithenai* derives from the PIE root ***dhe*** (set/put) https://www.etymonline.com/word/*dhe-

Comment: As cited in your source, thesaurus and treasury share with tethenai the same PIE root: -  *1823, "treasury, storehouse," from Latin thesaurus "treasury, a hoard, a treasure, something laid up," figuratively "repository, collection," from Greek thesauros "a treasure, treasury, storehouse, chest," **related to tithenai "to put, to place,**" from reduplicated **form of PIE root *dhe** "to set, put.*" https://www.etymonline.com/word/thesaurus

Comment: while a possible common root of tithe with tethenai is less clear. Tithe does not appear to have derived from Greek  : tithe,  *from Old English tēoþian, teogoðian), from a proposed Proto-Germanic *tehunþô, *tehundô (“a tenth”), with its nasal consonant being lost according to the Ingvaeonic nasal spirant law.* Ultimately from the PIE dekm- as shown above. https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tithe - Those who have access to the OED might give more precise information.

Answer (score 1):

To preserve information from comments:

- The verb is actually *tithemi* to put ([Strong 5087](http://biblehub.com/strongs/greek/5087.htm)).
  [- Nigel J](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429710/does-the-etymology-of-tithe-include-the-greek-tithenai?noredirect=1#comment1031114_429710) *Tithenai* may be the participle ([Nigel J](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429710/does-the-etymology-of-tithe-include-the-greek-tithenai?noredirect=1#comment1031114_429710)) or the present active infinitive ([sumelic](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429710/does-the-etymology-of-tithe-include-the-greek-tithenai/429850#comment1031115_429710)).
- *Tithe* wasn’t coined around 1200—it’s attested with the meaning given around 1200. The word itself is much older, as the Etymonline entry shows. It’s actually the more or less regular outcome of the PIE ordinal ‘tenth’. The modern ‘tenth’ is a more recent and transparent formation.
  [– Janus Bahs Jacquet](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429710/does-the-etymology-of-tithe-include-the-greek-tithenai?noredirect=1#comment1031121_429710)

From [user159691](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/429710/does-the-etymology-of-tithe-include-the-greek-tithenai?noredirect=1#comment1031130_429710):

- The roots appear to be different going back to PIE : [*tithe*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/tithe) has the PIE root [**dekm-** (ten)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*dekm-) - while *tithenai* derives from the PIE root [**dhe** (set/put)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*dhe-).
- As cited in your source, [thesaurus](https://www.etymonline.com/word/thesaurus) and treasury share with tethenai the same PIE root: - *1823, "treasury, storehouse," from Latin thesaurus "treasury, a hoard, a treasure, something laid up," figuratively "repository, collection," from Greek thesauros "a treasure, treasury, storehouse, chest," **related to tithenai "to put, to place,"** from reduplicated **form of PIE root *dhe** "to set, put."*
  while a possible common root of tithe with tethenai is less clear. Tithe does not appear to have derived from Greek : [tithe](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/tithe), *from Old English tēoþian, teogoðian), from a proposed Proto-Germanic *tehunþô, *tehundô (“a tenth”), with its nasal consonant being lost according to the Ingvaeonic nasal spirant law*. Ultimately from the PIE dekm- as shown above. Those who have access to the OED might give more precise information.